How to give this rectangle the correct height and elevation?
Based on this answer, I am considering the following code.
In the following MWE, one can see that the rectangle is not aligned with the baseline
and that the height of the rectangle depends on the following text.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\myTitle[1]
{\par\noindent{\textcolor[gray]{.8}{\leaders\vrule height 1ex\hfill}}{\large\bfseries\mbox{\ #1}}}

\begin{document}

\myTitle{Test}
\myTitle{p Test}

\end{document}


I would like to have a precise control on the height and the position on the rectangle :

I would like to be able to control the elevation of the bottom of the rectangle with respect to the baseline
I would like to be able to control the height of the rectangle

How can I achieve that?
PS: I'm okay with a totally different solution. My goal is to draw rule such as in the following picture:


You probably want to set the depth of the rule to zero, so add depth 0pt after height 1ex. (The comments to the answer you link suggest the same.)
